# fluent / fluent-plugin-mongo mongo_tail error on slow log collection system.profiling

Tags: mongodb, fluentd

`mongo_tail` work well with the normal collections Mongod, but get the error with the Mongo profiling collections system.profiling :

```
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: emit transaction failed  error_class=NoMethodError error=#<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_msgpack' for 2014-01-10 03:14:13 UTC:Time>
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /etc/td-agent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:33:in `to_msgpack' 
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /etc/td-agent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:33:in `to_msgpack' 
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /etc/td-agent/plugin/out_elasticsearch.rb:33:in `format' 
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/mixin.rb:96:in `block in format_stream'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/event.rb:54:in `call' 
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/event.rb:54:in `each' 
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/mixin.rb:93:in `format_stream' 
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/output.rb:235:in `emit' 
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/match.rb:36:in `emit'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/engine.rb:151:in `emit_stream'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluentd-0.10.41/lib/fluent/engine.rb:131:in `emit'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluent-plugin-mongo-0.7.1/lib/fluent/plugin/in_mongo_tail.rb:105:in `block in tailoop'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluent-plugin-mongo-0.7.1/lib/fluent/plugin/in_mongo_tail.rb:83:in `loop'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluent-plugin-mongo-0.7.1/lib/fluent/plugin/in_mongo_tail.rb:83:in `tailoop'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluent-plugin-mongo-0.7.1/lib/fluent/plugin/in_mongo_tail.rb:60:in `block in run'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluent-plugin-mongo-0.7.1/lib/fluent/plugin/in_mongo_tail.rb:59:in `loop'
  2014-01-10 11:53:37 +0700 [warn]: /usr/lib64/fluent/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fluent-plugin-mongo-0.7.1/lib/fluent/plugin/in_mongo_tail.rb:59:in `run'
```

How can I fix it, I want to pull slow Mongodb log to other place use fluent .

Comment: What version of the `msgpack` gem do you have installed? It looks like  support for Time serialisation was added to the `0.5.6.1` branch about 3 months ago: https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-ruby/pull/21

Comment: I had try to check and see that mongo_tail just work on normal collection except the "system.profile" where hold the slow query log. There is any way get the collections "system.profile" by fluent ?